# GCE disk disappeared from europe-west1-a zone

Tags: google-compute-engine

I attempted to start a VM instance using a predefined disk in zone europe-west1-a. I have been using the disk for a number of weeks. The VM startup never completed (the start activity did not complete and the instance never appeared in the VM list - so presumably the VM failed to startup).

When I tried to start the VM a second time, the disk was no longer available. The disk is also not listed under the "Disks" tab of compute engine.

I have bronze support package, so can't create a ticket with google.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should send a question about this using the grey *"Send feedback"* link at the bottom right of [Developers Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/) page. This may require looking at the logs for your specific project/account and is not something that we can solve here on StackOverflow.